# Why is my canvas animated arc glitching at the midpoint?

Tags: javascript, canvas

[Fiddle,](http://jsfiddle.net/watson/6ppDK/3/)
I tried to narrow it down to just whats important. I have a canvas arc which is 272 degrees accomplished with an offset. When the green animated arc reaches 135 degrees, it looks like this in Chrome and maybe other browsers:

[image]

Usually the entered value will not be exactly that, so it skips past the glitch very fast. But it would be really amazing if I could get rid of it completely. I am fairly new to canvas and don't know what to try. Thanks!!

Relevant JS:

```
function setGauge(valForGauge, val, distance){
    var time = 500; 
    time = time / (Math.abs(valForGauge - preValForGauge));

    if (valForGauge > preValForGauge) {
        var animate = setInterval(function(){
            if (preValForGauge == valForGauge)
                clearInterval(animate);
            else {
                preValForGauge++;
                drawValueArc(preValForGauge);              
            }
        }, time);
    } else if (valForGauge < preValForGauge) {
        var animate2 = setInterval(function(){
            if (preValForGauge == valForGauge)
                clearInterval(animate2);
            else {
                preValForGauge--;
                drawValueArc(preValForGauge);
            }
        }, time);
    } else if (valForGauge == 0 || valForGauge == preValForGauge) {
        preVal = val;
    }
}

function drawValueArc(val) {
    drawArc(ctx2, 57, 32, "rgb(230, 230, 230)", startRadians, endRadians);
    drawArc(ctx2, 57, 31, "#27AE60", startRadians, val);
}

function drawArc(ctx, radius, width, color, start, end) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx, cy, radius, (startRadians + offset) * deg2rad, (end + offset) * deg2rad, false);
    ctx.strokeStyle = color;
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.stroke();
```

Comment: looking into it, but it seems that when the animation ends, the circle is ending at the same angle as the very end of the arc.  I'll see what I can find

Comment: Also seems that the circle has to reset itself or can't handle some rotation at a certain point when it reaches half way, that's what the glitch is.  I'm sure you knew this, I just hope to help others help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly a bug with Chrome's (and Canary) implementation. If works fine in FireFox (Aurora). In Safari it's fine (although it took one year for it to animate it). Opera works fine too.

You should report the bug to Google from the browser (here is how):
https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

You can try this solution as a work-around:

```
var deg2rad = Math.PI / 180.001; //179.999
```

Updated fiddle incl. workaround:
http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/6ppDK/6/

There are many issues with the arc method in Chrome, some may or may not be related:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=245233
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=243996
http://www.twiddla.com/test/ChromeCanvas.html

Comment: Ken's always on top of it.

Comment: @watson SO is my new home.. :) Check out the work-around in the answer.

Comment: @watsoon Updated answer (the value worked in my Chrome so I guess this is something to be aware of as users can get different results). remember to accept answer if it helped with the problem. :)